# Inputting an apostrophe in my search box throws up an error

Tags: php, apostrophe

website running php 5.2. Inputting text in my search box containing an apostrophe throws up this message : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 's%' ORDER BY name,shortdesc ASC LIMIT 0,20' at line 1

Here is part of my search.php script. Any help would be appreciated.

function resultados(){

```
$acc         = $_GET['acc'];
$byartiste = ereg_replace("'","'",$_GET['byartiste']);
$bytitle     = ereg_replace("'","'",$_GET['bytitle']);
$L             = $_GET['L'];
```

Comment: Your PHP version is very badly EOL. It's long past the time to upgrade. https://php.net/supported-versions

Comment: You can try this one
**$text = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($text))**
or 
**$text = str_replace(array("'"), "\'", $text);**